# Multiply all elements of a list with each other once and not with themselfs

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested

i wrote this code to multiply all elements of a list like [a,b,c] with each other and not multiply with themselves and the result is this list:
[a*b , a*c, b*a , b*c , c*a , c*b]..
i only want to populate the resulting list with:
[a*b, a*c , b*c]
because the rest are duplicates in reverse.
can someone give me a helping hand because i cant figue this out!
many thanks in advance!

here is my code:

```
a = []
#list = [1,2,3,4,5]
def myf(a,b) :
    m = a * b
    return m


for i in range(1,6) : # or list 
    for z in range(1,6) : # or list
        if i  != z :
            val = myf(i,z)
            a.append(val)


print(a)
```

the outcome is [2,3,4,5,2,6,8,10,3,6,12,15,4,8,12,20,5,10,15,20]
while i want   [2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20]

Comment: Use a set instead of a list to accumulate the results, and there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: Change the second loop to `for z in range(i+1,6):` and remove the `if` condition.

Comment: with `i < z` you infer an ordering with `!=` not [In this case both ranges are the same!]

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is combination without repitation

which can be done as

```
from itertools import combinations
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = [a*b for a, b in combinations(l, 2)] # 2 is size of combination of list element you want

print(result)
```

without using this function, you are expection that for current element/value index you evaluate the element/values whose index is more than it. this can be done as

```
>>> result = []
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> for i, v in enumerate(l):
        for j, v2 in enumerate(l[i+1:]):                                             
            result.append(v*v2)                                              
>>> result
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18, 20, 24, 30]
```

Comment: great alternative method,,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are traversing the same elements in the first and second loops.

You can filter the traversed values by skipping the values in 2nd loop, which 1st loop has covered already.

Updated code is.

```
a = []
#list = [1,2,3,4,5]
def myf(a,b) :
    m = a * b
    return m

for i in range(1,6) : # or list 
    for z in range(i+1,6) : # or list
        if i  != z :
            val = myf(i,z)
            a.append(val)

print(a)
```

Output is

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20]
```

Comment: You could remove the `if i != z` there, since `z` is always greater than `i` with the way you set up the loops.

Comment: Yes @slothrop, I had minimally edited the OPs code for easier understanding.

Comment: This is great because one can do any calculation  within myf and get the list of paired results!

Answer (score 0):

You can start the second iteration through the values not from 1 but from the first value, so that all the pairs you're multiplying are in increasing order. Like that:

```
a = []
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i, value1 in enumerate(lst):
    for value2 in lst[i + 1:]:
        a.append(value1 * value2)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20]
```

Here `enumerate` returns pairs of current element's index and value. We need the index to know from hich element to start iterating for the second value.

`lst[i + 1:]` only returns elements from `(i + 1)th` to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
map_list = []
for i in list_a.copy():
  multiplier = list_a.pop(0)
  map_list.extend(list(map(lambda x: x * multiplier, list_a)))
```

And the output is

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
def multiply_list_elements(lst):
    product = 1
    for num in lst:
        product *= num
    
    result = product
    for num in lst:
        result /= num
    
    return result

# Example usage
my_list = [2, 3, 4, 5]
result = multiply_list_elements(my_list)
print(result)
```

The first loop will calculate the product of all elements in the list.

The second loop eliminates self-multiplication ensuring all elements are multiplied by all other elements except itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two level list comprehension with the first level enumerating elements up to the penultimate one and the second level fetching the subsequent items:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]

R = [a*b for i,a in enumerate(L,1) for b in L[i:]]

print(R)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20]
```